# how can I sort multiple avl trees together?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

given k avl trees(T1, T2, ...Tk).
all the trees together have n different numbers(T1 nodes+ T2 nodes+...Tk nodes = n )
I want to sort all of them together and print the numbers sorted from the the smallest to the biggest with the best efficiency possible.
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

On each AVL tree define a cursor (generator, iterator, ...) that will visit the nodes in-order.

Create a priority queue (like a binary min-heap) with *k* entries -- one for each AVL tree, and as key (priority) the value of the tree's current (cursor) node.

Then repeat as long as there are entries in the priority queue:

- Pull the first entry from the priority queue. This gives you a tree with a current node that has the least value (compared to all other "current" nodes).
- Output that current node's value.
- Forward the tree's cursor to the next node (according to in-order traversal).
- If this succeeds (i.e. there is a next node) then push this tree back on the priority queue with its new key (i.e. the value of its now current node). Otherwise, skip this step.

Comment: Any feedback on this answer?